# Error reading characters of string Person Class

Tags: c++, string, class

Have the parent class Person, child class Education part, and child of Education part - Teacher

each of them has public function void print();

I am put for example print function of education part in teacher.

```
void Teacher::print()

{
   cout << subject << "\n" <<position << "\n"<<degree<<"\n"<< endl;
    Education_part::print();
}
```

and it doesn't print debugger write Error reading characters of string and give -88897459855 answer.
When I write in educational part  print () like this `cout<<"hello"` and don't use my data from class - all working.

Here classes:

```
class Education_part :   public Person
{
public:             
                    Education_part();

                    Education_part(string phone,
                                 int paymant,
                                 string mAdress,
                                 string m_email);

      //getters/seters
public:
    string              get_Ph() const { return Phone; }
    int                 get_Pay() const { return Payment; }
    string              get_Adress() const { return adress; }
    string              get_email() const { return email; }


    void                set_Ph(string phone) { Phone = phone; }
    void                set_Pay(int paymant) { Payment = paymant; }
    void                set_Adress(string mAdress) { adress = mAdress; }
    void                set_email(string m_email) { email = m_email; }

    void                print();


private:

    string              Phone;
    int                 Payment;
    string              adress;
    string              email;

};

class Teacher :  public Education_part
{
public:

    Teacher();

    Teacher(string Subject, string Position, string Degree);

public:

    string              get_Subject() const { return subject; }
    string              get_Position() const { return position; }
    string              get_Degree() const { return degree; }



    void                set_Subject(string Subject) { subject = Subject; }
    void                set_Position(string  Position) { position = Position; }
    void                set_Degree(string Degree) { degree = Degree; }

    void                print();


private:

    string              subject;
    string              position;
    string              degree;

};
```

and here main

```
int main()
{
    
    Teacher::Education_part e2("805034521", 5988, "Kherson, Boguna 6, 122", "goward@gmail.com");
    
     Teacher t("Criminal Law", "teacher", "doctor of philosofy");
      
        
    t.print();
      

}
```

Comment: Why is `Education_part` a kind of `Person`? _See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)_

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PlEqhLJxA9KMngWb). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

When you create Teacher object, his parent class Person use default constructor `Education_part()`. I think that you default constructor don't initialize members of Education_part such as email, phone, etc. So to use another constructor you need to write `Teacher(string Subject, string Position, string Degree): Education_part("805034521", 5988, "Kherson, Boguna 6, 122", "goward@gmail.com");` instead of `Teacher(string Subject, string Position, string Degree);`.